# Powerpoint presentation slideshow in Debian

Tags: linux, presentation

I need something to play a PPT as a slideshow in Kali Linux.

I tried **OpenOffice.org**, but it just causes the whole thing to halt and **pptview** doesn’t display moving GIFs and videos.

Is there an application I have missed, or maybe a way to play them online? I just need to play the slideshow, no editing options.

Comment: Have you tried [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)? It was originally a fork of OpenOffice but its development is a lot faster and I believe it is a good way ahead of OO.